# Removing the default test suite from ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When I create a rails app I usually do it like:

```
rails new <app> --skip-test-suite
```

No I have an app where I forgot to add the param `--skip-test-suite` and I would want to use `RSPEC` instead of the default test suite. How can I get rid of the default? Can I just remove the `test` directory and what gems would I need to get rid of?

Comment: Just remove the test folder. `Test::Unit` is a part of `Ruby` standard library so nothing to remove.

Comment: Hey but generate will still generate test files then?

Comment: good point… I believe if you add `config.generators {|g| g.test_framework  :rspec, fixture: false}` it should generate test correctly for you given that you have `rspec` installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3, to totally remove TestUnit from your application, remove this line from your config/application.rb

```
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

And add this to config/application.rb

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```